# A heap of warnings and no image on the welcome/finish page

Tags: nsis

This is my first time using NSIS and I'm trying to make an installer that uses MUI2, but it's not going too smoothly. When I compile my code I don't get any errors, so it compiles, but I get a truckload of warnings. First it happened with a slightly complex installer, but I even made a super-simple one (still using MUI2) and I still get the same errors.
This is the resulting log:

```
MakeNSIS v2.46 - Copyright 1995-2009 Contributors
See the file COPYING for license details.
Credits can be found in the Users Manual.

Processing config: 
Processing plugin dlls: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Plugins\*.dll"
 - AdvSplash::show
 - Banner::destroy
 - Banner::getWindow
 - Banner::show
 - BgImage::AddImage
 - BgImage::AddText
 - BgImage::Clear
 - BgImage::Destroy
 - BgImage::Redraw
 - BgImage::SetBg
 - BgImage::SetReturn
 - BgImage::Sound
 - Dialer::AttemptConnect
 - Dialer::AutodialHangup
 - Dialer::AutodialOnline
 - Dialer::AutodialUnattended
 - Dialer::GetConnectedState
 - InstallOptions::dialog
 - InstallOptions::initDialog
 - InstallOptions::show
 - LangDLL::LangDialog
 - Math::Script
 - NSISdl::download
 - NSISdl::download_quiet
 - Splash::show
 - StartMenu::Init
 - StartMenu::Select
 - StartMenu::Show
 - System::Alloc
 - System::Call
 - System::Copy
 - System::Free
 - System::Get
 - System::Int64Op
 - System::Store
 - TypeLib::GetLibVersion
 - TypeLib::Register
 - TypeLib::UnRegister
 - UserInfo::GetAccountType
 - UserInfo::GetName
 - UserInfo::GetOriginalAccountType
 - VPatch::GetFileCRC32
 - VPatch::GetFileMD5
 - VPatch::vpatchfile
 - nsDialogs::Create
 - nsDialogs::CreateControl
 - nsDialogs::CreateItem
 - nsDialogs::CreateTimer
 - nsDialogs::GetUserData
 - nsDialogs::KillTimer
 - nsDialogs::OnBack
 - nsDialogs::OnChange
 - nsDialogs::OnClick
 - nsDialogs::OnNotify
 - nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog
 - nsDialogs::SelectFolderDialog
 - nsDialogs::SetRTL
 - nsDialogs::SetUserData
 - nsDialogs::Show
 - nsExec::Exec
 - nsExec::ExecToLog
 - nsExec::ExecToStack

!define: "MUI_INSERT_NSISCONF"=""

Changing directory to: "F:\Sami\Games\Mightier\Even Mightier Installer"

Processing script file: "F:\Sami\Games\Mightier\Even Mightier Installer\Even Mightier.nsi"
!include: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Include\MUI2.nsh"
!include: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\MUI2.nsh"
NSIS Modern User Interface version 2.0 - Copyright 2002-2009 Joost Verburg (F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\MUI2.nsh:8)
!define: "MUI_INCLUDED"=""
!define: "MUI_SYSVERSION"="2.0"
!define: "MUI_VERBOSE"="3"
!include: closed: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\MUI2.nsh"
!include: closed: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Include\MUI2.nsh"
!include: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Include\LogicLib.nsh"
!include: closed: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Include\LogicLib.nsh"
!include: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Include\Sections.nsh"
!include: closed: "F:\Sami\Applications\NSIS\Include\Sections.nsh"
Name: "Even Mightier Setup"
OutFile: "EvenMightier_v1.0Setup.exe"
InstallDir: "$PROGRAMFILES\Mightier\"
!define: "MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE"=""
!define: "MUI_UNFINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE"=""
!define: "MUI_ABORTWARNING"=""
!define: "MUI_ABORTWARNING_TEXT"="Are you sure you want to stop installing Even Mightier?"
!define: "MUI_ABORTWARNING_CANCEL_DEFAULT"=""
!define: "MUI_UNABORTWARNING"=""
!define: "MUI_UNABORTWARNING_TEXT"="Are you sure you want to stop uninstalling Even Mightier?"
!define: "MUI_UNABORTWARNING_CANCEL_DEFAULT"=""
!define: "MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VERIFYONLEAVE"=""
!define: "MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT"="This installer will install Even Mightier, an expansion for Mightier. It is recommended that you do not have Mightier open during the installation."
!insertmacro: MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro: end of MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro: MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro: end of MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define: "MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE"="LeaveDirectory"
!insertmacro: MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro: end of MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro: MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro: end of MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro: MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro: end of MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro: MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro: end of MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!define: "MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE_TEXT_LOCATION"="Please select the directory where Mightier is installed."
!insertmacro: MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro: end of MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro: MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro: end of MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro: MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro: end of MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
Section: "Separate Install" ->(SepInstall)
WriteUninstaller: "Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd
Section: "Overwrite Install" ->(OverInstall)
WriteUninstaller: "Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd
Function: "LeaveDirectory"
!insertmacro: _Switch
!insertmacro: end of _Switch
!insertmacro: _Case
!insertmacro: end of _Case
MessageBox: 0: "Directory does not exist!"
Abort: ""
!insertmacro: _Goto
!insertmacro: end of _Goto
!insertmacro: _Case
!insertmacro: end of _Case
MessageBox: 0: "There is not enough free space on the drive."
Abort: ""
!insertmacro: _Goto
!insertmacro: end of _Goto
!insertmacro: _EndSwitch
!insertmacro: end of _EndSwitch
FunctionEnd
Function: ".onInit"
StrCpy $1 "0" () ()
FunctionEnd
Function: ".onSelChange"
!insertmacro: StartRadioButtons
!define: "StartRadioButtons_Var"="$1"
Push: $R0
SectionGetFlags: $1->$R0
IntOp: $R0=$R0&0xFFFFFFFE
SectionSetFlags: $1->$R0
Push: $R1
StrCpy $R1 "$1" () ()
!insertmacro: end of StartRadioButtons
!insertmacro: RadioButton
SectionGetFlags: 0->$R0
IntOp: $R0=$R0&1
IntCmp $R0:1 equal=0, < +2, > +2
StrCpy $1 "0" () ()
!insertmacro: end of RadioButton
!insertmacro: RadioButton
SectionGetFlags: 1->$R0
IntOp: $R0=$R0&1
IntCmp $R0:1 equal=0, < +2, > +2
StrCpy $1 "1" () ()
!insertmacro: end of RadioButton
!insertmacro: EndRadioButtons
StrCmp "$R1" "$1" equal=0, nonequal=+4
SectionGetFlags: $1->$R0
IntOp: $R0=$R0|1
SectionSetFlags: $1->$R0
Pop: $R1
Pop: $R0
!undef: "StartRadioButtons_Var"
!insertmacro: end of EndRadioButtons
FunctionEnd

Processed 1 file, writing output:
Adding plug-ins initializing function... Done!
warning: uninstall function "un.mui.FinishPage.GUIInit" not referenced - zeroing code (165-170) out

warning: install function "mui.FinishPage.GUIInit" not referenced - zeroing code (188-193) out

Processing pages... Done!
Removing unused resources... Done!
Generating language tables... warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_INFO" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_INFO" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_INFO" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
warning: LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
Done!
warning: Variable "mui.Header.Text" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Header.Text.Font" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Header.SubText" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Header.Background" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Header.Image" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Branding.Text" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Branding.Background" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Line.Standard" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Line.FullWindow" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Button.Next" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Button.Cancel" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
warning: Variable "mui.Button.Back" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
Generating uninstaller... Done!

Output: "F:\Sami\Games\Mightier\Even Mightier Installer\EvenMightier_v1.0Setup.exe"
Install: 6 pages (384 bytes), 2 sections (2096 bytes), 436 instructions (12208 bytes), 155 strings (2342 bytes), 1 language table (322 bytes).
Uninstall: 5 pages (320 bytes), 
0 sections (0 bytes), 374 instructions (10472 bytes), 129 strings (1728 bytes), 1 language table (282 bytes).
Datablock optimizer saved 21677 bytes (~19.8%).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               50176 / 35840 bytes
Install code:                   3013 / 17704 bytes
Install data:                  12605 / 114468 bytes
Uninstall code+data:           24559 / 28918 bytes
CRC (0x425A3F9F):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                    90357 / 196934 bytes (45.8%)

46 warnings:
  uninstall function "un.mui.FinishPage.GUIInit" not referenced - zeroing code (165-170) out

  install function "mui.FinishPage.GUIInit" not referenced - zeroing code (188-193) out

  LangString "MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_COMPONENTS_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_INNERTEXT_COMPONENTS_DESCRIPTION_INFO" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_INSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTNOW" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_REBOOTLATER" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_CONFIRM_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_UNINSTALLING_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_ABORT_SUBTITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_REBOOT" is not set in language table of language 1033
  LangString "MUI_UNTEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT" is not set in language table of language 1033
  Variable "mui.Header.Text" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Header.Text.Font" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Header.SubText" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Header.Background" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Header.Image" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Branding.Text" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Branding.Background" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Line.Standard" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Line.FullWindow" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Button.Next" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Button.Cancel" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
  Variable "mui.Button.Back" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
```

In addition, no image displays on the left side of either the welcome or finish page, although I suspect that's connected to the above warnings.
Basically, I'd like to know what the problem is and how I should fix it. If anybody needs the code of my .nsi file please say and I'll add it to the question.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium (if that helps) and using the latest version of NSIS (2.46).

Comment: You should post your fix as the answer, and then accept it. That will let others know what the solution is.

Comment: @Dan: Yeah, I wanted to do that, but it said people with less than 100 rep need to wait 9 hours before doing that, and I'd figured it out real quickly. I've done it now.

Comment: Cool, just make sure you mark it as the accepted answer as well.

Comment: @Dan: Yeah I had to wait a day to be able to do that too XP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I took a careful look at an example and saw that I hadn't inserted the `MUI_LANGUAGE` macro in my code, which I didn't know was required. It fixed both the warnings and the disappearing welcome/finish images.
In my opinion it's kind of strange that it's required, but that's how it is anyway. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Comment: The MUI uses custom strings so clearly the strings have to come from somewhere. Since MUI_LANGUAGE is the last MUI macro you use it is also used to turn the MUI configuration defines into the final values (Which image to use etc)

Comment: It's really weird that this fact hasn't been added yet to the [readme](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html) after 5 years, I had to come here digging just to fix the display issue with a simple installer. The line is, however, found in the [examples section](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/Modern%20UI/Basic.nsi)